# Please, help me to translate these sentences

Tags: translation, grammar

could you please check, if I have translated these sentences in a right way? 
Thanks a lot! :)

1. How should it be possible, to design a standard school uniform, that all students would like it, while every student is individual?
   一件同一的校服怎么样可能形成(xing2cheng2)为了每个孩子喜欢他，每个孩子 虽然特别？
2. What do you want to achieve with inserting of a school uniform? 
   你用校服的施行(shi1xing2)想得到什么？
3. What sense does it make for parents to buy every year a new school uniform, if  child grows very quickly?
   要是一个孩子很快张(zhang)，父母有什么意义每年买一件新的校服？
4. Don't you think, that it is important for a child to develop himself  free?
   你们想孩子们随便的发展是不是重要？为什么？
5. How do you want to solve  costs-problems, if children need in summer another kind of a school-uniform ( as in winter)?
   你们怎么样想解决(jie3jue2)费用的问题要是夏天别的校服被需要？

Comment: You do not have the ability to write decent Chinese sentence yet. It is easy to translate the sentences for you, but it is hard to teach you to construct Chinese sentences without giving out extensive grammar lessons.

Comment: The English is not good either. If you like I can put it in good English first. If you start from a bad sentence, how will you arrive at a good translation? What language are you starting from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How should it be possible, to design a standard school uniform, that all students would like it, while every student is individual?
怎么可能设计出一套标准校服，让所有学生都喜欢它，而每个学生都是独立的个体 ?

What do you want to achieve with inserting of a school uniform?
你想透过施行校服实现什么？

What sense does it make for parents to buy every year a new school uniform, if child grows very quickly?
如果孩子成长得很快，父母每年购买一套新校服有什么意义？

Don't you think, that it is important for a child to develop himself free?
你不认为让一个孩子自由发展是很重要的吗？

How do you want to solve costs-problems, if children need in summer another kind of a school-uniform ( as in winter)?
如果孩子在夏天和冬天需要不同的校服，你如何解决费用的问题？

Comment: Hinen, hank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1.怎么可能设计一件标准的可以让彼此不同的所有学生都喜欢的校服？
2.你想通过校服的施行来达到什么目的？
3.如果孩子成长(grows)得很快，父母每年买一件新校服有什么意义？
4.你们难道不认为孩子们自由(free)地发展很重要?
5.如果孩子们在夏天需要另一种校服，你们想('打算'is better)怎样解决费用的问题？

To use 的(dé)地(dé)得(dé) correctly,
[you can read this page.](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Structural_particle_%22de%22)

In Chinese, the first sentence is always said without commas, so I translate it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Translations provided by the other guys seems unnatural to me. I reorganised the order of each sentence and used colloquial phrases and idiom. So don't use this for homework but this works fine in real life.

1. 众口难调,你怎么可能设计出让所有学生都喜欢的校服?
2. 要求学生穿校服的目的是什么?
3. 孩子们都在长身体,难道父母们要每年买一件新校服吗?
4. 你难道不觉得让孩子们自己做主自己的生活也很重要吗?
5. 孩子们需要冬,夏两套校服,你怎么解决费用问题?